# Stored procedures, Incorrect number of arguments bug?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an issue that is driving me crazy right now.
Yesterday I made a simple SP, it worked great then. Today, without any changes to the SP, it is not working at all. None of the SP works. I get the 1318 error code all the time. 
As I said, everything worked great yesterday.

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE DEFINER=`local`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_username`(
OUT match_name VARCHAR(50), 
str_id INT(5)
)
BEGIN
SELECT username INTO match_name FROM members WHERE id = str_id;
END
```

Simple SP to retrieve the name behind a id that is called from the mysql client with:

```
CALL get_username(37);
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
`get_username`(
OUT match_name VARCHAR(50), 
str_id INT(5)
)
```

You need 2 parameters, you need to pass in a variable parameter for that output parameter